# In C++ if a pointer is returned and immediately dereferenced, will the two operations be optimized away?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

In C++ if I get and return the address of a variable and the caller then immediately dereferences it, will the compiler reliably optimize out the two operations?

The reason I ask is I have a data structure where I'm using an interface similar to std::map where find() returns a pointer (iterator) to a value, and returns NULL (there is no trivial .end() equivalent) to indicate that the value has not been found.

I happen to know that the variables being stored are pointers, so returning NULL works fine even if I returned the value directly, but it seems that returning a pointer to the value is more general.  Otherwise if someone tried to store an int there that was actually 0 the data structure would claim it isn't there.

However, I'm wondering if there's even any loss in efficiency here, seeing as the compiler should optimize away actions that just undo the effect of each other.  The problem is that the two are separated by a function return so maybe it wouldn't be able to detect that they just undo each other.

Lastly, what about having one private member function that just returns the value and an inline public member function that just takes the address of the value.  Then at least the address/dereference operations would take place together and have a better chance of being optimized out, while the whole body of the find() function is not inlined.

```
private:
V _find(key) {
   ... // a few dozen lines...
}


public:
inline V* find(key) {
    return &_find(key);
}

std::cout << *find(a_key);
```

This would return a pointer to a temporary, which I didn't think about.  The only thing that can be done similar to this is to do a lot of processing in the _find() and do the last step and the return of the pointer in find() to minimize the amount of inlined code.

```
private:
W* _find(key) {
   ... // a few dozen lines...
}

public:
inline V* find(key) {
    return some_func(_find(key)); // last steps on W to get V*
}

std::cout << *find(a_key);
```

Or as yet another responder mentioned, we could return a reference to V in the original version (again, not sure why we're all blind to the trivial stuff at first glance... see discussion.)

```
private:
V& _find(key) {
   ... // a few dozen lines...
}


public:
inline V* find(key) {
    return &_find(key);
}

std::cout << *find(a_key);
```

Comment: Note that "actions that just undo the effect of each other" is a very thin set, for instance it doesn't work for `&*p`, nor `x + n - n` and so on...

Comment: find never returns NULL. It just returns the iterator to end if the element is not found. **NULL** and **iterator::end()** are not equal.

Comment: I'm aware they're not equal, that's why I said (there is no trivial .end() equivalent).  I'm using NULL as my special value here to indicate that it was not found.  It doesn't really even make sense to implement a .end() in my case because there is no directionality to the iteration.

Comment: can't you use references rather than pointers?

Comment: So, why don't you just have `find` pass a reference? Does it *need* to pass a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

`_find` returns a temporary object of type `V`. `find` then attempts to take the address of the temporary and return it. Temporary objects don't last very long, hence the name. So the temporary returned by `_find` will be destroyed after getting its address. And therefore `find` will return a pointer to a previously destroyed object, which is bad.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code.  Just a simple mistake, the text explains what I was trying to do also.

Comment: @Doug Treadwell: Is V a reference type? Otherwise you are returning a pointer to a temporary.

Comment: @DougTreadwell You're still taking the address of a temporary, which is at best no allowed. At worst, that temporary will be destroyed at the end of the function and thus you will have a pointer to a dead object.

Comment: Ah good point.  Hadn't thought about that one.  I was just cooking up this thought as I was posting, so I guess that's a good reason why it won't work.  I didn't think see that one.  If you can edit your post to reflect the fact that V** return was a mistake and not the code I intended to write I'll accept.

Comment: @doug easy to fix the question so that it does not return a temporary

Comment: @Nicol, upvoted you but it looks like there is a way around the temp return problem, it was just an oversight on a hasty correction to the original writeup.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it go either way. It really depends on the compiler and the level optimization. Even when it does get inlined, I've seen cases where the compiler will not optimize this out.

The only way to see if it does get optimized out it is to actually look at the disassembly.

What you should probably do is to make a version where you manually inline them. Then benchmark it to see if you actually get a noticeable performance gain. If not, then this whole question is moot.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking (manual benchmark) but seems like it would depend on a lot of things like compiler make, platform, etc.  Whereas copy elision seems pretty common.  I was wondering if it was like that, and it sounds like it's not...

Comment: I just noticed (along with everyone else) that in your case you're taking the address of a temporary so it won't work in the first place. My answer obviously applies to cases where the value is live after the function ends.

Comment: Perhaps the thing to do is to do the majority of the processing in some _find() function and then do the last step and return of the pointer in find(), saving as much as possible on the size of the inlined code.

Comment: Yes, shortening that function will definitely increase the chances that the compiler will inline it. But one to note is this: If the `find` is only called in that one place and is not declared extern or exported in anyway, the compiler will probably modify the function's parameters/return value to make it more efficient (assuming it doesn't inline it completely).

Answer (score 1):

Your code (even in its second incarnation) is broken. `_find` returns a `V`, which `find` destroys immediately before returning its address.

If `_find` returned a `V&` to an object that outlives the call (thus producing a correct program), then the dereference would be a no-op, since a reference is no different to a pointer at the machine code level.

Comment: What would the return value be then to something that doesn't exist?  A reference to a static member variable with value NULL perhaps?  Still thinking about this, just wanted to be sort of responsive.